# codeigniter : update function model and controller

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-2

I don't know what I am doing wrong in this.
If anyone could help!
cause i have tried all solutions...
also undefined variable `$data error`

```
          /************************/                                                             
public function edit_stud($student_id)
{

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('full_name', 'full_name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('father_name', 'father_name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('roll_no', 'roll_no', 'required');


    if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
    {
        $data['student']= $this ->stud_model->update_student($student_id, $data);
        $this->load->view('edit_form' , $data);
    }
    else
    {

    $full_name = $this->input->post('full_name', true);
    $father_name = $this->input->post('father_name', true);
    $roll_no = $this->input->post('roll_no', true);

    $data = array(


    'full_name'=>$full_name ,
    'father_name'=>$father_name ,
    'roll_no'=>$roll_no,



    );

    $student_id = $this->stud_model->update_student($student_id,$data);
    redirect('/stud/edit_stud/'.student_id);

    }
}
```

//***********************Model in CI***//////////////

```
public function update_student($student_id,$data)
{
    $this->db->set($this->table_name,$student_id, $data);
    return $this->db->update_id();
}
```

Comment: What's the error u get?

Comment: Why you are updating student in `if` condition when your validation fails?

Comment: Also @RubyRose please explain you problem statement what you require exactly? If its only `undefined variable $data error` then your `if` condition is executed that is `validation error`

Comment: I am trying to write edit function in student controller for updating the fields in sql_db...I mean if i write the id only the fields get filled with old data fetched by the same function!

Comment: @RubyRose why you are updating student `$data['student']= $this ->stud_model->update_student($student_id, $data);` in `if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)` because if you write update code in `if statement`, you won't get $data there. Hence you will get error `undefined variable $data error`

Comment: what should I do then???

Comment: here is what i think i am trying to do:

Comment: http://localhost/sample_ci_project/index.php/stud/edit_stud/1    when i pass the one parameter along with controller it would fetch the data of that id in the fields

Comment: Check answer of @thomasw_lrd. He has explained it properly as per your requirement.

Comment: An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: ArgumentCountError

Message: Too few arguments to function stud::edit_stud(), 0 passed in E:\xammp\htdocs\sample_ci_project\system\core\CodeIgniter.php on line 532 and exactly 1 expected

Answer (score 1):

$data is never defined in the first part of your IF statement.

In particular this line

```
$data['student'] = $this->stud_model->update_student($student_id, $data);
```

is the problem.  If the form validation is false, you don't want to update the student.  Remove that line, and everything should be fine.

Unless you do want to update student even if the validation fails (This is a bad idea, IMO).  Then your controller would look like this

```
public function edit_stud($student_id) {

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('full_name', 'full_name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('father_name', 'father_name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('roll_no', 'roll_no', 'required');

    $full_name = $this->input->post('full_name', true);
    $father_name = $this->input->post('father_name', true);
    $roll_no = $this->input->post('roll_no', true);

    $data = array(
        'full_name' => $full_name ,
        'father_name' => $father_name ,
        'roll_no' => $roll_no,
     );

    $student_id = $this->stud_model->update_student($student_id, $data);

    if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
        $this->load->view('edit_form' , $data);
    } else {
       redirect('/stud/edit_stud/'.student_id);
    }
}
```

Comment: also it only loads the view!

Comment: Well, debug that your query is getting called. In your model in the update_student, add this line right after the update is called:                                                                   
       echo $this->db->last_query(); die;                                                        
 then run the page and see if the query is legit and also works if you manually ran it in the database. Then remove that line when done.

Comment: <form method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('stud/edit_student') ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for suggestions i have solved the problem i was having
in my code i did some renditions...posting the correct answer for
anyone else, having same sort of problem.
this is the controller code.

```
/*****controller code*****/
/***************************edit student ******************************/
    public function edit_stud($student_id)
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('full_name', 'full_name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('father_name', 'father_name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('roll_no', 'roll_no', 'required');
        if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
        {
            $data['student']= $this ->stud_model->get_student($student_id);
            $this->load->view('edit_form' , $data);
        }
        else
        {
        $full_name = $this->input->post('full_name', true);
    $father_name = $this->input->post('father_name', true);
        $roll_no = $this->input->post('roll_no', true);
          $data = array(
        'full_name'=>$full_name ,
        'father_name'=>$father_name ,
        'roll_no'=>$roll_no,
        );
        $student_id = $this->stud_model->update_student($student_id,$data);
        redirect('/stud/edit_stud/'.student_id);    
        }
    }

    /************************delete student ************************/
    public function delete_stud($student_id)
    {
         $this ->stud_model->delete_student($student_id);
         redirect('/stud/');
    }
/***********************model code *******/
/************to get student id*********/
public function get_student($student_id)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from($this->table_name);
        $this->db->where('id',$student_id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
         if($query->num_rows() >0)
         {
             $return =  $query->row();
         }
        else
        {
            $return = 0;
        }
        $query->free_result();
        return $return;
    }
/*****************update function***********************/
    public function update_student($id, $data)
    {
        $where = array('id' => $id);
        $this->db->update($this->table_name, $data, $where);
    }
```